# Sane and Proper way to go from Xcode 4.2.1 to 4.3?

Tags: ios, sdk

I have Xcode 4.2.1 which came with an installer and put itself and numerous associated files into ~/Developer  I downloaded Xcode 4.3 which does not include an installer, just the app.  Should I simply replace 4.2.1 which is in ~/Developer/Applications or should I do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Xcode.app in `/Application` directly.

The first time you run Xcode 4.3, you are prompted to remove older Xcode in `/Developer`, you can cancel it and remove `/Developer` in later.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html

Comment: Thank you.  Sort of strange there was no pdf associated with the new download that gave some of the basic info in the link you provide.  That would be more Apple's style.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: Actually, that info is on the page you downloaded Xcode 4.3 from.